# I have a problem with classes and inputs in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I just started learning about classes and am trying to build a calculator
that tells people how much they need to tip the waiter as a small project
but instead of entering myself the information i want that a user will do it himself so it will suit hes needs. 
now i think i built it right, the computer accepts the inputs but when i try to call
the **return_answer()** function i get an error that says: 
*AttributeError: tip_calculator object has no attribute 'return_answer'*
can someone please explain to me what i am doing wrong and how to fix it?
thanks in advance :)

```
class tip_calculator:
    def __init__(self,bill,amount_of_diners,precent):
        self.bill = bill
        self.amount_of_diners = amount_of_diners
        self.precent = precent

        def return_answer(self):
            print("The amount you need to pay is: ", precent * bill / amount_of_diners ** bill * 1000)

calc = tip_calculator(int(input("What was the bill?: ")), 
                      int(input("With how many people did you eat?: ")),
                      int(input("what '%' do you want to give the waiter?: ")))

calc.return_answer()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the indentation:

```
class tip_calculator:
    def __init__(self, bill, amount_of_diners, precent):
        self.bill = bill
        self.amount_of_diners = amount_of_diners
        self.precent = precent

    def return_answer(self):
        print(
            "The amount you need to pay is: ",
            self.precent * self.bill / self.amount_of_diners ** self.bill * 1000,
        )


calc = tip_calculator(
    int(input("What was the bill?: ")),
    int(input("With how many people did you eat?: ")),
    int(input("what '%' do you want to give the waiter?: ")),
)

calc.return_answer()
```

Your `return_answer` method was indented wrongly inside the initialiser (`__init__`). Also, in your `return_answer`, when you want to access class members like the fields `bill`, `amount_of_diners` and `percent` you need to do it with `self` because they are members of your class and not local variables to your method.